# Simplifying $\frac{dy'}{dy}$ where $y=f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

I'm feeling a bit brain-dead, perhaps it has just been a long day.  But here is the problem, I think it's a simple one:

I have a function $y=f(x)$, of which I then take the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$.  Finally I take the derivative of the function with respect to itself:

$$ \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

How can I simplify/refactor this funky derivative? Ideally to express the derivative in terms of $y$ and derivatives thereof.

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Could you give just a tiny bit more info?

Comment: How is the derivative operator $d/dy$ defined?

Comment: It's the derivative of the argument at constant x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to get all fancy... We want to solve for $\frac{dy'}{dy}$ and by the chain rule we have

$$\frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dy'}{dy}$$
so, solving for our quantity, we get
$$\frac{dy'}{dy} = \frac{\frac{dy'}{dx}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{y''}{y'}$$

Answer (score 3):

The chain rule might suggest an answer something like $\dfrac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

For example with $y=x^n$ you might get $\dfrac{n(n-1)x^{n-2}}{nx^{n-1}}=\dfrac{n-1}{x}$. 
To check this, at least for positive $x$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=nx^{n-1}=ny^{(n-1)/n}$ so $\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = (n-1)y^{-1/n}=\frac{n-1}{x}$

On the other hand for $y=ce^{kx}$ you might just get the constant $k$.  To check this, $\frac{dy}{dx}=kce^{kx}=ky$ so $\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = k$ as expected

Curiously for $y=\tan(x/2)$ you get the same $\tan(x/2)$

Answer (score 2):

$dy/dx=f'(x)$ is a function of $x$, just as $f$ is.  In order to differentiate the function $f'(x)$ with respect to $y$, a variable related to $x$, it must somehow be expressed as a function of $y$.

An analogy which may be helpful:  $x^2-4$ is a function of $x$.  Its derivative with respect to $x$ is $2x$, i.e., the function which takes $x$ to $2x$.  Suppose we wrote $y=x^2$.  Then $\dfrac{d}{dy}(x^2-4)=$ $\dfrac{d}{dy}(y-4)=1$, a constant.

Introduce the notation $f^{-1}$ for the inverse function of $f$ over some suitable interval $I$ in which $f$ is increasing or decreasing (which is required for the inverse to exist).  Then $x=f^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in f(I)$, and so $f'(x)=f'(f^{-1}(y))$ for $y\in f(I)$.  Having thus expressed $f'$ as a function of $y$, we can calculate its derivative with respect to $y$.  Differentiate via the chain rule (Baby Rudin 5.5) and get $\dfrac{d}{dy}f'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dy}f'(f^{-1}(y))=f''(f^{-1}(y))\dfrac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)$.  Now use Baby Rudin exercise 5.2 to get an expression for the second factor in this last expression.

Comment: +1: I feel like this is the only answer which carefully explains the situation at hand. I like to think of this using manifolds: $f':\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function to be differentiated, and $y = f(x)$ is coordinate system we are using on the domain. As any chart, $f$ should be injective (at least in a small enough neighborhood).